# Saving Excel file without formulas?

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

People are usually asking the opposite, but I wonder if I can save .xlsx in openpyxl without formulas.

I expect something like:

```
wb.save(filename = path, write_formulae = False)
```

I could not find it in manuals, do you have any idea?

Comment: Do you want the formula cells *cleared* or replaced with their current *values??*

Comment: All the cells with formulae values should be cleared. As example when you save files in xlwt, you can see blank cells instaead of formulae.

Comment: I can't see any sense in such an option. When reading an existing file you have the choice of preserving either the formulae or the values. This choice will be reflected when you save a file. But if you add any cells with formulae then the formulae will be saved when you save the file. If you don't want that then just don't add any formulae.